# How to show cluster of points on OpenStreetMap?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to create Open street map that contains cluster of no. of points. If I zoom on map then splits points.

Like if I zoom on map[image]

Now click on cluster..shows like this...[image]

So I need Js for open Street Map not for Leaflet.

Comment: I know this is implemented in leaflet but need this in open street map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking here - leaflet is a map viewing library and OpenStreetMap is a tile / data source. They are totally different, independent things. You can display OpenStreetMap **tiles** very easily in Leaflet. Tiles are the background mapping that is basically pngs tiled together and you can't interact with it.

And you can also display **points of interest** (things you can interact with on the map, like your markers above) from OpenStreetMap (or anywhere else) very easily in leaflet. This seems to be what you are trying to do.

To do this you will need to:

- Download the points of interest in a suitable format (e.g. [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html)) has shapefiles for common points of interest for many different countries and smaller regions. This could be a huge answer, as there are many different ways of doing that, but since I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve I will leave it at that.
- Convert them to geoJSON format
- Display on the map using leaflet - and it looks like you need leaflet marker cluster to aggregate your markers.

Comment: can you please give me a sample example for open layer cluster which uses open layer map, javascript or JSP.